# xpath: Finding an element in the context of the element before it and after it

Tags: c#, vb.net, xpath

I am using xpaths to run automation developed in C# using VB. I am having trouble finding an element in the context of two different elements. I need to do this because the element shares the same name with other elements on the page but the elements following and preceding it are unique.

I have also upload a file to help you understand, I want to find date in the context of whats before it and after it.

http://www.filedropper.com/example

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div> this is a test 
   <div> <h1> test1 </h1> </div>
   <div> <h1> date </h1> </div>
   <div> <h1> time1 </h1> </div>
   <div> <h1> test2 </h1> </div>
   <div> <h1> date </h1> </div>
   <div> <h1> time2 </h1> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: post your code example here on this page within your initial question not in a web link

Comment: I am afraid this is not a free code site where people download your file, try to go through it many times to understand the issue that is not specified clearly, debug that file and send you back with your *wish list* completed.... Please show the code, errors you have gotten if any..  :-)

Comment: file download worked fine for me:

`<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div> this is a test 
 <div> <h1> test1 </h1> </div>
 <div> <h1> date </h1> </div>
 <div> <h1> time1 </h1> </div>
 <div> <h1> test2 </h1> </div>
 <div> <h1> date </h1> </div>
 <div> <h1> time2 </h1> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
/html/body/div/div/h1[../following-sibling::*[1]/h1/text() = " time2 " and ../preceding-sibling::*[1]/h1/text() = " test2 "]
```

`following-sibling::*[1]` return the first following sibling. As the div and h1 elements are nested, you have to go up one level in the hierarchy first.

Comment: Ok let me see if I can clear it up a bit, the code is up there thanks to someone. I want to select the second "date" and then confirm it is the right "date" by checking to see if the element before  "test2" and the element after "time2" are the right elements. Does that clear things up?

Comment: I changed my answer, should work now